# How many functions to create a stackoverflow?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, windows-xp, stack-overflow

On Windows XP using Visual C++ with 2GB of RAM, how many functions would have to be on the stack at the same time to create a stackoverflow? (i.e. in recursive functions)

Is there a simple way I could calculate this for other similar situations?

Comment: The stack is a megabyte by default.  The smallest possible stack frame is 4 bytes in an optimized build.  Practical ones are much larger.  RAM has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I can overflow the stack in just one function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to know just from the compiler. Stack overflows happen because of overflowing the stack. The stack's size grows depending on the arguments a function takes, local variables the function uses, and compiler optimizations. There are even some C99 functions I believe that will allocate space directly from the stack.

The limit of the stack's size is determined by a *compiler* switch, not how much RAM you have in your computer. So how many calls it takes to overflow has more to do with compiler settings than your memory.

It's not something you can determine a priori. At least, not trivially.

Comment: Actually, one can determine the image's stack limit at the runtime by looking at its SizeOfStackCommit field in the PE Optional Header (offset 72). As Hans said, it is usually 0x10000 (1MB).

Answer (score 0):

You can try an infinite recursion..It is one of the common causes of a stack overflow.

`int f()
{
g();
}
int g() {
f();
}`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. - Besides, I'd have expected it to produce a stack overflow in less than 5 seconds, but instead it timed out: http://ideone.com/QoWtS ;)